# right now vs at the moment

Tags: phrase-usage

Somebody is using the computer right now.

If I change this sentence to a passive one, can I say

"The computer is being used *right now*."?

The answer in the textbook is "The computer is being used *at the moment*."

Could anyone explain the difference between "right now" and "at the moment"?

Comment: in this case, either one is fine and idiomatic, and they both have the same meaning.

Comment: 'Right now' is less formal than 'at the moment'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The computer is being used now.
>
> The computer is being used at the moment.

These are identical statements. **At the moment** means "right now."

You might also hear:

> The computer is currently being used.
>
> The computer is currently in use.

Your sentence is incorrect, however. It should be:

> Is the computer being used right now?

Comment: I have downvoted your answer on your false assertion that the question: **Is the computer being used right now?"" is the passive form of the statement: **The computer is being used right now.** You have merely turned the statement into a question. I shall vote your answer up again if you correct it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your vote so I could fix my error. I removed the word "passive."  I'm not sure why I put it there in the first place lol.